# How to scan dynamoDB in lambda?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

so I have a table of 10 items, each item has about 5 keys (name,experience,level, etc). Now, I want to scan that table, get each item as an object and add it to an array and then JSON stringify that array and return it.

I just need help with the scanning code and getting all items and putting it into an array.

Here's my code I have currently.

```
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(); 
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) 
{

    var returnArray = {
        "cards": {}
    }
    getCards();

    function getCards() {//Not sure how to write this function

        var params = {
            TableName : "toBeApprovedTable",
            Key: {//not sure what to put here, since I want all items, and not searching through keys.
            },
        };

        dynamodb.scan(params,function(err,data)
        {
            if(err)
            {
                console.log("error in scanning");
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("scanning success!");
                //Not sure what to do here.
            }
        });
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after scrapping through Google + AWS docs.

Here is how to scan a table for all elements in the table. My return is a map, which contains an array of elements. Each element is a map of my object.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) 
{

    var returnArray = {
        "cardsToBeApproved":[]
    };
    getCards();

    function getCards() {//Not sure how to write this function

        var params = {
            TableName : "toBeApprovedTable"
        };

        dynamodb.scan(params,onScan);
    }

    function onScan(err,data)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log("unable to scan table");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("scan succeeded");
            data.Items.forEach(function(card)
            {
                console.log("my card name is " + card.name);
                var cardStringified = JSON.stringify(card);
                returnArray.cards.push(card);
            });
            callback(null,JSON.stringify(returnArray));
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: drop a comment if you need me to explain a line :)